# Sequence a fixed number of times

Tags: r, sequence

I'm looking to create an incremental sequence:

I have a data frame
`dt <- data.table(Customer = c("a", "b", "c"), count = c(3, 4, 5), ACV = c("30","20","30"))`

```
     Customer count ACV
1:        a     3  30
2:        b     4  20
3:        c     5  30
```

I am replicating this data frame by count using: 
`{dt[rep(seq(1, nrow(dt)), dt$count)]}`

The output I receive is

```
    Customer count ACV
 1:        a     3  30
 2:        a     3  30
 3:        a     3  30
 4:        b     4  20
 5:        b     4  20
 6:        b     4  20
 7:        b     4  20
 8:        c     5  30
 9:        c     5  30
10:        c     5  30
11:        c     5  30
12:        c     5  30
```

However I want the ACV column to increment by 1...therefore, output desired is

```
    Customer count ACV
 1:        a     3  30
 2:        a     3  31
 3:        a     3  32
 4:        b     4  20
 5:        b     4  21
 6:        b     4  22
 7:        b     4  23
 8:        c     5  30
 9:        c     5  31
10:        c     5  32
11:        c     5  33
12:        c     5  34
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `dplyr` and add `row_number()` to first `ACV` in the group.

```
new_dt <- dt[rep(seq(1, nrow(dt)), dt$count)]

library(dplyr)

new_dt %>% 
   group_by(Customer) %>%
   mutate(ACV = as.numeric(ACV[1]) + row_number() - 1)


#   Customer count   ACV
#   <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 a            3    30
# 2 a            3    31
# 3 a            3    32
# 4 b            4    20
# 5 b            4    21
# 6 b            4    22
# 7 b            4    23
# 8 c            5    30
# 9 c            5    31
#10 c            5    32
#11 c            5    33
#12 c            5    34
```

---

In base R, we can use `ave` for the same and use `seq_along` instead of `row_number`

```
new_dt$ACV <- with(new_dt, ave(as.numeric(ACV), Customer, 
                   FUN = function(x) x[1] + seq_along(x)) - 1)
```

---

Using `data.table` we can do

```
new_dt[, new_ACV := as.integer(ACV[1]) + seq_len(.N) - 1L, by = Customer]
```

Comment: Thanks. Can we max the increment out at a given number. for instance instead of ACV if we had quarters                                                                                                
`                                                                                                                      
 Customer count Quarter
 4 b            4       3
 5 b            4       4
 6 b            4       5
 7 b            4       6
`                                                                              
can we change line 6 quarter to 1?

Comment: @Nik It is not clear to me what you are trying to do. Can you explain it ?

Comment: just posted a response to my initial question

Answer (score 0):

One approach with data.table syntax:

```
# example dataset with ACV as numeric
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(Customer = c("a", "b", "c"), count = c(3, 4, 5), ACV = c(30,20,30))

# expand the number of rows according to "count"
dt <- dt[rep(1:.N, count)]

# increment ACV
dt[ , ACV := ACV + 1:.N - 1, by=Customer]
```